# Ubuntu 22,04 server on digital ocean - daily spikes. why?

Tags: 22.04, cpu-load

Once a day,for about an hour, cpu usage approaches 100% and disk i/o is about 400MB/sec (read). I will generate and analyse some performance metrics, but wonder if someone knows the answer to this off the top - P.S. Apache log shows very low usage during the period.

Here is a link to Digital Oceans activity graph for the most recent 14 day period for my server.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Pav6Nzm_VagWNzlaOq82IQgGMOHuv859/view?usp=drive_link

thanks

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of your GoogleDrive data into your question via an [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1476954/edit), because external data may disappear rendering this question useless for further visitors. Thanks.

Comment: Use `sudo journalctl` to check your system's logs. Read `man journalctl` to learn about the `--since=` and `--before=` options. Also check for queued `cron` jobs. Look at `root`'s crontab in `/etc/crontab`, and the user crontabs in `/var/spool/cron/*`. Click on my userid, read my profile. After the philosophy/rant, there are `journalctl` hints.

Comment: Thanks for the tips vis-a-vis journalctl and cron.

Comment: OK! The 'culprit' was the absence of a swap file.  This is the default for a simple Ubuntu droplet deployed on Digital Ocean. After I installed a swap file with twice the capacity of max real memory, the spikes went away